# Shapefile to geojson and set the right crs

Tags: r, geojson, shapefile, r-sf

I am working with a form file, from a city in Colombia ([Cali](http://datos.cali.gov.co/ne/dataset/capa-de-barrios-de-santiago-de-cali/resource/71202aa7-1720-4d89-879d-3831e318837e?inner_span=True)). I need to convert the file to geojson format, however when loading it there is a problem with the crs, because when loading the geojson and trying to graph it, nothing appears.

This is the zip file with the data

http://ws-idesc.cali.gov.co:8081/geoserver/idesc/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=idesc:mc_barrios&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP

```
library('mapview')
library('sf')
library('geojson')
library('geojsonsf')

## Read shapefile
cali <- read_sf("E:/Users/Rafae/Downloads/mc_barrios/mc_barrios.shp")
cali$barrio[5] <- "Area en Desarrollo - Parque del Amor"
Encoding(cali$barrio) <- "latin1"
mapview(cali)
```

**works**

[image]

```
## Convert to geojson
geojson_cali <- as.geojson(cali)
cali_new <- geojsonsf::geojson_sf(geojson_cali)
mapview(cali_new)
#write(geojson_cali, "Cali.geojson")
```

**doesn't work**

[image]

```
#geojson_sf(geojson_cali) %>% st_transform(st_crs("+proj=utm +ellps=GRS80 +datum=WGS84")) %>% 
st_make_valid() %>% mapview()
#cali_new %>% st_transform(st_crs(cali)) %>% st_make_valid() %>% mapview()
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: I don't think your `geojson_cali <- as.geojson(cali)` is doing what you think it's doing. Perhaps you want `geojson_cali <- geojsonsf::sf_geojson(cali)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the conversion to geojson is forcing a WGS 84 crs on the data without transforming it first. Just transform the `cali` object to this projection before converting it to geojson, so that this no longer matters.

```r
library('mapview')
library('sf')
library('geojson')
library('geojsonsf')

## Read shapefile
cali <- read_sf("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/mc_barrios/mc_barrios.shp")
cali$barrio[5] <- "Area en Desarrollo - Parque del Amor"
Encoding(cali$barrio) <- "latin1"

cali <- cali %>% st_transform(4326)

cali_geojson <- sf_geojson(cali, simplify = FALSE)

cali_new <- geojson_sf(cali_geojson)

mapview(cali_new)
```

[image]